# git commit -a isn't skipping the staging area

Tags: git, git-bash, git-commit

Hello I'm a beginner and I'm learning to use Git with a Youtube toutorial. The instructor did `git commit -a` to directly commit files without using `git add` command.
But, when I used the command on my system, I get this for some reason -
[screenshot of git bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWiai.png).

Output -

```
$ git commit -a
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        file1.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Can someone tell why is it happening.

Thanks.

Comment: Please copy/paste ouput here as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: i added the output as text.

Comment: See the link I added at the top of your question. It looks very similar to yours.

Comment: Hi @Adityashu It worked for your instructor because we can assume that his file1.txt is tracked instead of untracked. When the file is untracked to being with, it cannot be committed (i.e. git commit -a). When the file is tracked (meaning it was added to staging before with `git add file1.txt`), then future execution of `git commit -a` would work now.  To explain further what I mean by "was added to staging before", if a file has been added to staging with `git add <filename>` once, then this file will now become tracked by default from this point on (after the very first `git add`).